# Error: Cannot find module 'truffle-expect'——truffle migrate

Tags: truffle

Thanks to Kshitij's answer at another page! but I still have this error after applying this answer. which drives me crazy! Sorry for post the question as a answer-_-

After run truffle init and truffle compile, it works fine.
the contracts that I compile are examples from truffle:(when I change to HelloWorld it's the exactly same error)

- ConvertLib.sol  MetaCoin.sol  Migrations.sol

other information is:

- ubuntu 14.04.2
- node -v v7.10.0
- npm -c 4.2.0
- Truffle v3.3.2 (core: 3.3.1)
- Solidity v0.4.11 (solc-js)

Every time I run "truffle migrate" it shows Error, with or without testrpc running

error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'truffle-expect'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
    ...
```

installing truffle-expect won't work, would anyone give me a hand please?

Comment: try downgrading the truffle version, probably 3.2.5. This is what I'm using right now.

Comment: You should mention that you have tried https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19185/truffle-migrate-error-cannot-find-module-truffle-expect

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/477) and I'm sure truffle will have a fix for it very soon.

### Workaround 1

For now, try running `npm install -g truffle-expect truffle-config web3`, which seems to work for several people.

### Workaround 2

If that doesn't work for you, try installing an earlier version of truffle until the fix is applied.

e.g.

`npm i -g truffle@3.2.2`

Comment: I tried both of 1&2, it still  has the Error cannot find module 'truffle-export', but thanks anyway

Comment: hmm, you're probably using truffle globally, so it was my mistake in number 2. Try running `npm un -g truffle` to uninstall, then my updated command above to install earlier version again (includes `-g` flag).

Comment: I'm sure I had to close and open the console window after installing, thought I'd mention it in case that was your issue

Comment: thanks you guys, after running 'npm un -g truffle'  to uninstall & 'npm i -g truffle@3.2.2' to reinstall 3.2.2 version. I found my truffle version is still 3.3.2. (And I close and open the console window after installing)